# Solar seller provided wiring diagram: Is this diagram of any use or unreliable/inefficient?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, load, schematic

**A solar equipment seller provides this wiring diagram** (not mine):

[image: Schematic solar]

There are three terminals on the solar charge controller: `Solar IN`, `Battery` and `Load` however `Load` is not used in this example. The question is, does this work anyway? I mean, can the charge controller charge the battery anyway with a continuous load attached to it? So what will happen exactly when using this? Any thoughts on this?

The first thing I can think of is that there is not a battery protection, it can drain the battery completely when there is not enough solar power available. The only reason I can think of why doing this is to bypass a current limit. The main question is, is it possible to charge the battery anyway when it is connected like this assuming the solar panel can provide enough power to charge it?

Comment: It's just a diagram. It does not depict how much power panels can generate or how much batteries are charged by solar or discharges by inverter load. So depending on components and loads and how cloudy it is, it may or may not work.

Comment: Load can mean a large resistor to dump excess power.  This is common in wind systems.  Some people put the resistive heating element into their water heater, so it's not really wasted.

Comment: Add some switches for easy control.

Comment: @codebeat please provide a source for your image otherwise it's plagiarism

Comment: @VoltageSpike Are you serious? Really? Common.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325015/do-the-referencing-guidelines-apply-to-images-as-well-as-text

Comment: @VoltageSpike I told you about the source, it is stated in the question. Anyway, it is a part of a screenshot I take (of a Chinese seller), not a copy of a file. It is like a photo of a building. Besides, it doesn't seem to be very unique because when you search with Google, with use of the picture above, you will find tons of the same diagram with the same or different equipment. I don't know which one was the first. So yeah maybe you are right in some way but common, this is ridiculous. Just a simple diagram that is widespread across the internet.

Comment: @VoltageSpike And also, when I put the source (link) to the seller, it can be seen as a commercial activity.  I don't want to promote a seller (or a website of a seller).

Comment: You should provide a source, all you have to do is link to where you saw the picture. It's a general rule of the internet and good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is how you do it. There is nothing unreliable or inefficient about it.

The load terminal on the charge controller is an output that can be switched on and off depending on the battery state. The current out of that port is also likely measured and included in the status the screen displays.

The reason it is not used for the inverter is that the inverter can draw HUGE currents. Like for a modest 400W load, you're looking at 33A.

The only downside to this arrangement is that you can't use the charge controller to turn the inverter on and off based on the battery state. Instead the inverter will use it's own internal low-voltage cutoff logic.

In most cases it is totally fine to charge and discharge the battery at the same time. The battery doesn't "see" any of that. If you put 3 amps in while drawing 10 amps out, the battery just "sees" 7 amps out. Yes, this *could* confuse the charge controller, but I doubt it would. The charge logic for lipos and lead acid batteries are both pretty simple. If the battery is pulled down somewhat by the inverter the controller will just keep trying to charge it, which is fine. Note the battery is not actually charging when this happens, as the charge current is all going too the load; thus there is no risk of overcharging the battery.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with what I would call more of a wiring diagram or block diagram than a schematic.

Presumably, the charge controller would still charge the battery if it has enough excess power above what any connected load would draw, but the charge controller documentation would provide more information.

Power inverters invariably have undervoltage lockouts, so they will stop supplying power once the battery has fallen below a certain threshold voltage.  That would prevent the battery from discharging completely. The  load connected to the charge controller also has an undervoltage lockout so there's no danger of completely discharging the battery there either.

Comment: Hai, thanks. Yeah, that is true about undervoltage lockouts, didn't notice that. But the voltage will rise again after some minutes because there is no load. Will the power inverter switch on again and after a second or so switch off again and again and again and again.......  Is it possible the electronics will die when this frequently occurs?

Comment: @Codebeat There's typically also hysteresis built in, so before starting again the voltage has to rise some number of volts above the UVLO point.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram connects the inverter direct to the battery probably because the inverter draws such a huge current - more than the controller can handle in its pass-through to the 'load' terminal. This seems to be a common setup.

It isn't particularly inefficient. If anything it's *more* efficient as the inverter connection direct to the battery avoids any though-the-controller drop.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to remove charge controller and replace it with a constant voltage DC/DC converter or is that a bad idea? For example: a max 60V panel and a DC/DC (protected with a diode) to 12V (12.6V) and a 12V battery. Or maybe use a trickle charger instead of such charge controller?

Comment: Still recommend the charge controller. It's doing two things for you: optimizing the power transfer from the panel (that’s what MPPT is), and tailoring the charge voltage to the battery state-of-charge.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. But if the charge controller is a clever one that monitors the state of the battery, then it will have no idea what state the battery is in when the inverter is turned on.

Ideally, you would connect the inverter to the load terminals of the charge controller. But first check the maximum current you can draw from those terminals against the current draw of the inverter.

Comment: That is really a good point, can the charge controller determine the state of battery with a load attached to the battery. If not, what will happen? Tries to charge it continuously?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best ever way to connect up a system, but it is certainly *a* way to do it.  It's probably also close to best if you have a heavy intermittent load and a light-weight solar panel and charger.  Such a setup, in turn, would save you money on your charger and could well be the least expensive way to set things up *for that situation*.

On the other hand, if you had a system where significant power would go to the load at the same time that charging is happening, then in order to intelligently charge the battery you'd want a charger and load manager (either in one box, or modules that talked to each other) that was both smarter and heavier duty than is implied by the diagram.

Such a scenario would involve a steady power drain all the time, or even a "smart" system that only turns on power to some appliances (well pumps, air conditioning, whatever) when the power available from the solar panels is sufficient, and leaves it off otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Load can mean a large resistor to dump excess power, like when the batteries are fully charged. This is common in wind systems. Some people put the resistive heating element into their water heater, so it's not really wasted.

This is also more common in off-grid systems.  Grid tied systems don't have this issue, since the grid can take nearly all excess power that a home system can generate.

See image below for an example of how the **LOAD terminal** is used.

[image]
[Image source](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Sizing-a-stand-alone-off-grid-wind-turbine-battery-Erturk/e7531710e508c254624fa4f6b6c1e89e8af349d0)

> can the charge controller charge the battery anyway with a continuous load attached to it?

This is merely a \$power\text{ }in >power\text{ }out\$ question.  If that statement is true, then yes it'll work and you'll want to circle back on adding the dump load for protection.
As usage happens when there is no sun, or \$power\text{ }in <power\text{ }out\$ then you'll have to rely on the inverter to shut down when the input voltage reaches the cut off limit, in order to prevent the battery from becoming damaged.

Comment: The load is shown in the diagram, an inverter. Consumes at idle (nothing connected to it) 100mA to 500mA or so?

Comment: @Codebeat *three terminals on the solar charge controller: Solar IN, Battery and Load*  It's on the charge controller not the inverter.  Check the image.

Comment: @Codebeat see updated answer with example of load terminal being used **DUMP LOAD**

Comment: That's not what load means in this case. I have an inverter like this and it's a switched output to run devices like lights.